# Audio and video keep skipping without any reason in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, video, media

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and copied all my music files to the Music folder. Then, I opened Rhythmbox music player and clicked on song to play it, but it's constantly skipping all the music in just microseconds. The process is so fast that I can't understand why this is happening. After few seconds there was a prohibited symbol appearing at the bottom of the screen.

[image: prohibited symbol]

After some time I tried to play a video and the same thing happened. All the videos skipped one by one in just a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y

if it does not work i think is a bug, you kan make Alt+F2
then you write ubuntu-bug rhytmbox
and you follow the instruction
i hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I believe I have resolved so I created an Ask Ubuntu account to hopefully be able to help you resolve it as well.

Below is my post on Ubuntu Forums explaining how I believe it to be a bug in the jack detection and a post on Reddit that I found with a solution.

Good luck!

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2477755&p=14107029#post14107029